# Using SED, TR or AWK to capitolise the first letter

Tags: awk, sed, grep, tr

I have a giant text file of potential passwords that I use for ethical pen-testing. I want to get a bit more variation of my passwords by getting the first letter of a given password to be capitalized. In the past I used

```
sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g"
```

and

```
sed 's/\b\([[:alpha:]]\)\([[:alpha:]]*\)\b/\u\1\L\2/g'
```

to either cap the first letter (first example), or cap first letter and force the rest to lower case (second example). But now I have a new problem. My source file looks like this:

```
password
p@ssword
123password
!!123password
!@#000password
```

I would like the output to be:

```
Password
P@ssword
123Password
!!123Password
!@#000Ppassword
```

`sed`, `tr` or `awk` need to be smart enough to look for the first a-z character and capitalize that, instead of focusing on the first character, seeing that it is a number or symbol and moving on without fixing my word.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

`sed` will do just fine as it defaults to replace only the fist match if you omit the **g**lobal modifier:

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)/\U\1/'
```

But in general you wouldn't do this manually but let the cracking tools do the magic automatically with *rules* enabled.

Comment: Thank you my friend!! I tried to +1 your answer, but I dont have enough reputation :-(

Comment: @Tyson0317 see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for how to accept it regardless of whether or not you can upvote it.